# Cleaning up bowties

Tags: technique, chisel, inlay

I am new to hand tools and to bowties. After several videos and several attempts, I think I am getting the hang of the inlaying part.

The making of the bowties still puzzles me though. Most tutorials say you should clean them up with a chisel but then gloss over the process.

Should I pare with the grain? It feels difficult to achieve a straight line throughout. And should I start the cut below the surface?

Light mallet taps with the grain? I’ve had the most success with this method, although also not super consistent.

Lay them on the face and chisel vertically, similarly to how the matching cavity is made? Last time I tried that the grain split on me :( (maybe it was the time to sharpen, or maybe acacia is too crumbly — all my previous attempts were on oak).

I would really appreciate any advice as at this point I spend almost the same time cutting and fiddling with the bowtie as inlaying it.

Comment: It’s always time to sharpen :) You might consider making your bowtie out of a thicker piece and then cut away the back to prevent a lot of the splitting.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Good points! I assume you recommend the third method?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, yes on the sharpening. Not really necessary to worry about splintering on the back since this is hidden inside the joint, and with hand tools only (i.e. no bandsaw!) it can be really hard to saw pieces this size. If one did start thick and want to thin before inserting the bowtie it's much faster and more efficient to just plane away the excess.

Comment: @Graphus Interesting point on sawing small items. I am using a ryoba on a Chris Schwarz Roman bench (which incidentally is the item in need of bowties… 10+ of them). I have been clamping the bowtie to a block of wood clamped to the bench with holdfasts, which works ok. Other two options I’ve though of for a low bench are a moxon vise or a wooden screw clamp (either of those still held by holdfasts). Is there a better method I’m missing?

Comment: Sorry, for clarity I was referring specifically to resawing above, a rip cut to split a small workpiece like this. Because there's so little to hold on to, and the edges are now these weird opposing angles, the best clamping option is squeeze the bowtie face to face, which directly fights the action of the saw. There are ways around this, but it's just so much simpler to put one end of a bowtie against a planing stop and just have at it with a plane. And again, assuming you did deliberately start over-thick, which I don't see as at all necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bowties/butterflies don't have to be perfect, in fact some asymmetry might be considered to be desirable rather than a defect. As far as I've seen historical examples are rarely up to the standards of today, which isn't surprising really since they're largely (completely?) a feature of vernacular furniture and not something seen coming out of the workshops of craftsmen of the highest order.

Now if *your* bowties need to 'perfect' then you practice making them until you get to that level. By practice I don't mean doing them in projects as the need/opportunity arises and hoping to see progress (this'll work but it's a terrible way to hone skills). It means sitting down and making four, six, even ten bowties one after another *each time you practice*<sup>1</sup> — and possibly using a selection of different species too, since every species will present its own set of difficulties in making a visually flawless bowtie<sup>2</sup>.

Or, you do them with a power router and template, live with the machine-made look that results, but get near-perfect results immediately and repeatably.

> Should I pare with the grain?

Sometimes you'll want to do this (although I think primarily towards the end of the process when you're going for a sharp inside corner *if* desired).

> Lay them on the face and chisel vertically, similarly to how the matching cavity is made?

Yes. IME and from observation of others doing them by hand you'll primarily want to chop them.

This doesn't have to be done with a mallet or hammer, because this is removing wood from an edge and because of the orientation of the cut relative to the grain it can sometimes be done entirely using hand pressure, or by pressing on the end of the chisel handle with e.g. your shoulder, or your chin pressing on the back of your fist. But this will entirely depend on your chisel's overall length, the bevel angle, your sharpening level and, remember, the wood itself — hardness, grain orientation, whether the grain is plain or interlocked are all factors in the resistance it will put up.

Do remember though:

**A saw should be doing most of the work**
Just like with forming dovetails, the chopping should be a refinement process, not a creation process — the bulk of the shaping should have already been accomplished by sawing. How close to your layout lines you've sawn is a matter of individual skill and the saw being used, but I'd suggest aiming to have no more than 1mm (1/25") to shave away from the edges.

> I would really appreciate any advice as at this point I spend almost the same time cutting and fiddling with the bowtie as inlaying it.

That may be entirely appropriate, since the bowtie has to be as neat as your standards require, and it then forms the template for the mortise/pocket it goes into.

It may feel that this is "too slow" or "slower than it should be" but by what metric? For any given craftsperson at any given time, this is an *it takes as long as it takes* operation.

Some basic tips to follow.

- Use the widest chisel available, if possible use one that's wider than the length of the bowtie 'arm'. This is one of the reasons I bought a 2" chisel first opportunity I had.
- Make sure whatever chisel you're working with is *sharp* sharp. And if it blunts during the process, stop and sharpen.
- Knife your layout lines rather than just using a pencil. Fine pencil lines are plenty accurate, but a chisel can't register into them the way it can into a knife line.
- Good lighting can make a huge difference; if you can't properly see what you're doing accuracy and speed can both suffer and good light is the first step.
- Consider getting some sort of vision aid. Doesn't have to be an OptiVisor or even one of its inexpensive clones, cheap reading glasses are a bit of a secret weapon for this.
- If possible raise the workpiece up a little higher than your standard workbench height; over time your back will thank you. Note however that the higher you go the more you'll want to use a mallet/hammer.

---

> maybe it was the time to sharpen

If you're in any doubt about a chisel being sharp enough it's extremely likely it isn't :-)

If I can give you some cornerstone advice for where I think you are in your woodworking journey, practising sharpening is of absolute importance for the learner/developing hand-tool woodworker. Your process needs to give consistently good results, fairly effortlessly and, IMO quickly — while honing is not a race by any means, *and speed isn't necessarily something to directly practice for*, you do need to get to the point that stopping work to sharpen doesn't feel like too much effort<sup>3</sup>.

Stropping little and often (as carvers often do) is one good way to retain peak sharpness with almost zero time penalty, taking you out of 'the zone' as any long, involved sharpening process — more than five minutes? — will tend to do.

Freehand stropping takes moments, literally 10 seconds or less; a quick hone on stones/diamond plates or honing + stropping should really take no more than three minutes all-in since there should be so little steel to remove.

---

<sup>1</sup> You didn't think you'd only need to do this once, r-right? :-)

<sup>2</sup> Plus in a 'dense' practice mode like this you'll more easily notice and retain how the grain of a specific piece of wood you're working with can help or hinder you (compared with observations made weeks or months apart).

<sup>3</sup> Which is probably how >95% of people feel early on, it certainly was for me and most of the woodworkers I know.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, helpful and encouraging answer — as always! To clarify, I am happy with imperfect and asymmetrical. Just want to avoid curved sides (which complicate the inlay) and sloping (which compromises the fit). Your perspective on time is useful — I guess I just felt I was doing something wrong (probably I am) because making the bowtie itself rarely seems the focus of tutorials (and therefore I deemed it easier).

Comment: Remember, @stanch, the people making/writing the tutorials are already practiced (and one would hope, good) at doing what they're teaching you to do. Anyone who is good at their craft (wood, sport, art, driving, whatever) makes the difficult look easy. They also have a nasty tendency to forget to include small details that the newcomer doesn't know just because through years of practice it's become second nature and "obvious" to the teacher. They forget that the new guy doesn't know what he doesn't know.

Comment: stanch, 100% what @FreeMan just said. The assumption of "obvious" aspects of something is part of what sometimes — even often :-( — makes for imperfect tutorials, something that's super frustrating for the learner. Regrettably space or time constraints factor into this, in which case it's nobody's fault per se. But, it's sadly the case that skilled people *often* don't make the best teachers; those good with their hands can't be expected to be equally good with words, and can struggle to communicate clearly and/or concisely (while being aces at *demonstrating*).

Comment: I considered myself to be a pretty decent soccer player (footballer, for Graphus' benefit ;), but I _sucked_ when it came time to coach my kid's team. I had a hard time describing to them what came naturally to me, and was really frustrated when they just didn't get it right away. I know, I wasn't expert when I started, but by the time I was coaching, I just frustrated myself and the kids. One season was more than enough for me.